# Process crashed: Bad access due to invalid address

Tags: android-studio

---

---

Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:10/QSR1.210802.001/7603624:userdebug/dev-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
Timestamp: 2022-01-07 08:00:40+0000
pid: 9013, tid: 9031, name: Thread-21  >>> com.example.androiddemo <<<
uid: 10146
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x97977f78
eax f66c0160  ebx f1df3a74  ecx 7373616c  edx c9c9f9c8
edi 12ed1ff8  esi c9c9f9c0
ebp cb280818  esp cb280780  eip f19d5305

backtrace:
#00 pc 00287305  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so!libart.so (offset 0x14b000) (art::gc::Heap::GetInstances(art::VariableSizedHandleScope&, art::Handleart::mirror::Class, bool, int, std::__1::vectorart::Handle<art::mirror::Object, std::__1::allocatorart::Handle<art::mirror::Object>>&)+4277) (BuildId: 26b0fc8885e87fc8f11e1081b83a9b8e)
#01 pc 00117657  /data/local/tmp/re.frida.server/frida-agent-32.so
#02 pc 00117348  /data/local/tmp/re.frida.server/frida-agent-32.so

---

Comment: need use   android9 system

Answer (score -1):

That's too bad.  WSA is Android 11.  We are this close to having this working. We can launch twitter, for example, but we get this crash log.

```
frida -U --codeshare pcipolloni/universal-android-ssl-pinning-bypass-with-frida -f com.twitter.android
Spawned `com.twitter.android`. Use %resume to let the main thread start executing!

Process crashed: Bad access due to invalid address

Build fingerprint: 'google/redfin/redfin:11/RD2A.211001.002/eng.latteu.20211111.210152:user/release-keys'

Revision: '0'

ABI: 'x86_64'

Timestamp: 2022-01-12 20:13:11-0500

pid: 5886, tid: 5909, name: Thread-2  >>> com.twitter.android <<<

uid: 10068

signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xb5d8ed32

rax 000070bcc67cf6e0  rbx 000070bbb5afa0a8  rcx 54a07175d3ac76b5  rdx 000000000000123d

r8  0000000000000002  r9  0000000000000000  r10 00000000703096b0  r11 0000000000000000

r12 000000000000123d  r13 00000000b5d8ed2e  r14 00000000702a7438  r15 000070bc867cea10

rdi 000070bc867cea10  rsi 000000007031da00

rbp 000070bbad9fb020  rsp 000070bbad9faf50  rip 000070bbb67556da

backtrace:

  #00 pc 000000000078a6da  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so!libart.so (offset 0x643000) (MterpInvokeVirtual+218) (BuildId: d0a458400cb956a162aabaef91898b45)

  #01 pc 0000000000163099  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+25) (BuildId: d0a458400cb956a162aabaef91898b45)

  #02 pc 00000000000fa0a8  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar (java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericReturnType)

  #03 pc 0000000000392c7f  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so!libart.so (offset 0x2cc000) (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.17079065513659061432)+335) (BuildId: d0a458400cb956a162aabaef91898b45)

  #04 pc 000000000077672f  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so!libart.so (offset 0x643000) (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1103) (BuildId: d0a458400cb956a162aabaef91898b45)

  #05 pc 000000000018434c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so!libart.so (offset 0x183000) (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+140) (BuildId: d0a458400cb956a162aabaef91898b45)

  #06 pc 000070bb12d46330  <unknown>

  ***

  [Pixel 5::com.twitter.android]->
```